# MS Word - field code of file name without file extension

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I want to have a field code in word that is the filename, but without the file extension. This is as a reference in the footer. The document reference is the same as the document filename, but without the file extension.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

### There is not without coding.

What the field displays is a filename the way the operating system displays it. If the user has left display of common filename extensions turned off, it will not display.

Here is Microsoft's [documentation on the FILENAME field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-filename-field-a2946f1b-d822-47dc-ba32-4482aece26bc).

It would be possible to write a macro that would store the filename without the extension in a document property or variable, but I would not care to undertake creating such a field.

If the user does not like seeing the extension, tell the user to turn off the display on his/her computer.